# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre poner #!/usr/bin/python y no ponerlo?

Tags: python, script, unix, rutas

Yo mismo siempre ocupo muchas veces estas líneas `#!/usr/bin/python` al principio de mi script de *Python*, pero no sé por qué es útil. Tengo entendido que si en la terminal ejecuto `python script.py` no me causará problemas si mi script no le anteceden estas líneas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El inicio mediante `#!` se denomina [shebang](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) y es una característica relacionada con el uso de shells Unix.

El carácter `#` es un comentario en muchos lenguajes de programación, en concreto en Python, pero en este caso es también el carácter de comentario del *shell*.

Si vas a ejecutar tu programa poniendo:

```
$ python codigo.py
```

no necesitas ese comentario inicial (que python ignorará de todas formas por coincidir que el `#` es también el comentario en python).

Pero si en unix le das permiso de ejecución al archivo (con `chmod +x codigo.py`), entonces puedes intentar ejecutarlo sin especificar qué intérprete usar, así:

```
$ ./codigo.py
```

En este caso quien intentará ejecutar el script es el *shell* que estés usando (bash es el más común). El *shell* espera que el script esté escrito en el lenguaj del shell. Si no hubiera el *shebang* al principio, entendería que  lo que contiene el fichero debe ser ejecutado directamente por el *shell* y esto obviamente te causará errores porque el código python no es lenguaje de shell.

Pero si el fichero comienza con el *shebang*, entonces el *shell* usa ese comentario para saber qué intéprete debe cargar para ejecutar el resto del archivo. En tu caso, al poner:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

estás indicando al *shell* que cargue el ejecutable `python` de la ruta `/usr/bin` y que le pase este fichero como parámetro.

**Cuidado**, esta no suele ser la mejor opción si tienes en tu sistema múltiples versiones de python o entornos virtuales. Al usar el *shebang* estás **fijando** qué intérprete concreto usar, por lo que la ejecución mediante `./codigo.py` a lo mejor no es lo mismo que mediante `python codigo.py`, pues la primera estaría usando de forma prefijada `/usr/bin/python` como intérprete, mientras que la segunda estaría usando la versión de `python` que aparezca primero en el PATH.

Si quieres tener la misma flexibilidad a la hora de elegir qué python usar, pero mediante el *shebang*, lo que suele ponerse es:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Esto causa que el *shell* use como intérprete `/usr/bin/env`, pasándole como parámetros `python`  y el nombre del script en cuestión. En este caso la versión de `python` que se ejecutará será determinada por `/usr/bin/env`, que utilizará el `PATH`, por lo que sería lo mismo que haber puesto en la línea de comandos `python`.

Comment: Gracias, me quedo clarísimo. Muy buena respuesta